# Convert [Future<Object,Error>] to Future<[Object],Error>

Tags: swift, parallel-processing, functional-programming, future

Is there any way I can parse through the code below and return the value of it as an array Future<[Object],Error> . I'm using the [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) future implementation

```
return apiService.getArrayObject()
   .flatMap(NetworkQueue.context) { (arrayObjects: [ArrayObject]) -> Future<[Object], Error> in
      let objects = arrayObjects.map {
         apiService.getObject(of: $0.objectId)
      }
      return objects // ERROR since objects is [Future<Object,Error>] rather than needed output
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sequence

```
   return apiService.getArrayObject()
      .flatMap(NetworkQueue.context) { (arrayObjects: [ArrayObject]) -> Future<[Object], Error> in
          let objects: [Future<Object, Error>] = arrayObjects.map {
              apiService.getObject(of: $0.objectId)
          }
          let sequenceFuture: Future<[Object], NoError> = objects
                    .sequence()

         return sequenceFuture
    }
```